# LinkedHashMap entrySet's order not being preserved in a stream (Android)

Tags: java, android, java-stream, linkedhashmap

I'm creating a very simple form validation utility for a sign up screen, and I'm running into some unexpected behavior concerning `LinkedHashMap` and a stream created from its `entrySet`.

I'm storing validation results in a `LinkedHashMap`, with the following ordering of statements:

```
Map<ValidationResult.SignUpField, Boolean> fieldStatuses = new LinkedHashMap<>();

fieldStatuses.put(EMAIL, isValidEmail(emailAddress));
fieldStatuses.put(USERNAME, isValidUsername(username));
fieldStatuses.put(BIRTHDAY, isValidBirthday(birthday));
fieldStatuses.put(PASSWORD, isValidPassword(password));
fieldStatuses.put(CONFIRM_PASSWORD, password.equals(confirmedPassword));

List<ValidationEntry> invalidFields = aggregateInvalidFields(fieldStatuses);
```

One particular iteration yields all of the above fields invalid except for "confirm password". Using a simple for loop over the entry set and omitting valid results, the invalid results appear in the following order:

- Email
- Username
- Birthday
- Password

I then attempted to make use of the subset of Stream API's available on Android (targeting version 25 with a min of 19, hence the lack of `Collectors.toMap()`):

```
private static List<ValidationEntry> aggregateInvalidFields(Map<ValidationResult.SignUpField, Boolean> fields) {
    List<ValidationEntry> invalidFields = new ArrayList<>();
    fields.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue())
            .forEachOrdered(entry -> {
                ValidationResult.SignUpField field = entry.getKey();
                invalidFields.add(new ValidationEntry(field, lookUpErrorCode(field)));
            });
    return invalidFields;
}
```

But that code yields the following order:

- Birthday
- Password
- Username
- Email

What exactly is happening here, why is the result of the stream not honoring the insertion order of the `LinkedHashMap`? Note that if I swap out `forEachOrdered` with `forEach`, it's still not insertion ordered.

Comment: can you show your insert code?

Comment: sure, updating now

Comment: What is `invalidFields`?

Comment: It's an `ArrayList`, I'll update that code too

Comment: Can you also tell us what are you using for stream API?

Comment: I'm using the subset of Java Stream API's available on Android.

Comment: Is `fields` the same map as `fieldStatuses`?

Comment: Yeah, I'll just add the rest of the method body and the call to that method.

Comment: Weird. I tried if I could reproduce the problem with a `Map<String, Boolean>`, but my list comes out with the insertion order, no matter is I use `forEach()` or `forEachOrdered()`.

Comment: What if you used an enum value? That's what `SignUpField`'s type is.

Comment: So why aren’t you using an `EnumMap`?

Comment: I assume that if you ditch the stream library and just iterate through it by hand that it works right?  If so then I suspect that the Android stream operation may not obey `forEachOrdered(...)` or maybe the order is not sequential order out of the `entrySet()`.

Comment: With an enum I still get `[EMAIL, USERNAME, BIRTHDAY, PASSWORD]`.

Comment: Could you try to reduce this to a [mcve]? It's hard to know if you left out something important.

Comment: @Gray, that's what I was thinking, I'll probably stick with the loop for now

Comment: @Avi That doesn't make any sense. The keys and values are inserted in the same order. And he's actually iterating over entries, not values.

Comment: @Avi not true, I'm calling `entrySet()`

Comment: @shmosel I'll work on that in a bit, this has turned out to be one helluva tangent from the actual stuff I was trying to get done :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behavior is a known bug in Android's 7.0 / 7.1 implementation of LinkedHashMap.

The LinkedHashMap's collection views' spliterators for `entrySet`, `values` and `keySet` correctly report that they are `ORDERED` but actually they aren't because the spliterator implementation of the parent class (HashMap) is used internally.

This behavior has already been [documented](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/7ae7ae73754c8b82a2e396098e35553d404c69ef%5E%21/#F0) in the Javadoc and workarounds are also proposed there.

The [fix](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/9efb6d12ce4d2ffedb73d6e9887ea2c89f8ec129) has been commited on 2016-08-16 and will appear in the next Android release.

For clarification: Google became aware of this bug at first in 2017-01, so the "fix" mentioned above was an accidental fix. If they had known about this problem earlier, the resolution would have been included in 7.1

Comment: So I'm not crazy! Thank you for the insight.